Unable to resolve window load event
I am now having a whole html string, from  to , and need to create the page from it and await the new html string to load before continuing next.
I first tried:
let writeHTMLAndLoad = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        document.open();
        window.addEventListener("load",resolve());
        document.write(strHTML);
        document.close();
    });
}
await writeHTMLAndLoad();
//Code continue after...

But the script just directly continued. The html is seens written. But the page, mainly images and some html elements, just not loaded at all
I tried to put resolve without parenthesis, the script changed to await forever.
The same scenario, await forever, apply to cases of seaparting resolve (with or without parenthesis) into a dummy function
let writeHTMLAndLoad = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        function dummy() {
            resolve();
        }
        document.open();
        window.addEventListener("load",dummy);
        document.write(strHTML);
        document.close();
    });
}
await writeHTMLAndLoad();
//Code continue after...

But I found the load event can be successully triggered, if I deliberately force the script to continue by resolving directly after document.close();
let writeHTMLAndLoad = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        function dummy() {
            console.log("Loaded")
        }
        document.open();
        window.addEventListener("load",dummy());
        document.write(strHTML);
        document.close();
        resolve();
    });
}
await writeHTMLAndLoad();
//Code continue after...

In this case, the console.log("Loaded") printed out in the middle of the scirpt continued after. So it seems the document.write() is not affecting the load event.
May I know how I can resolve successully of the window load event?
I have to use the window load event as the indicator, as I have to use the images loaded.
I currently separated the code that intended to process after the load event into another function and asked the dummy function to call it. But in this case my script just separated into two large parts and prefer not to use this approach. So I would be really appreciated if the load event can be resolved correctly and so the code can be looked logically continue.
I know document.write is not a good practice. I want to get rid of it too. So feel free to recommend another method.
And the same scenario, image not loaded and continued, even I replaced the document.write to normal DOM manipulation as below:
let tempDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(strHTML, "text/html");
document.documentElement.innerHTML = tempDoc.documentElement.innerHTML;


Your document.write erases all script from the page

This is an X/Y problem. I do not see any situation where you would need document.write to do what you want. also why the promise/await in the first place? Is this just to see what happens?

I know document.write will erase all things. I'm intended to do that, so I added document.open() to make sure all possible stuffs are erased.
As said in the question, I now have a completely different and full (from  to ) document HTML string. The HTML string is generated from another server that I can't be controlled. So it seem's like using document.write is the most plausible way. But feel free to recommend another way. I just knew there's a DOMParser way to parse the whole HTML string into a document object. But I'm not sure how to replace the whole existing document next

I don't think the above two "duplicated" questions answered my case. My question is mainly focused on the window.addEventListener("load",...
If you say the document.write erased all scripts. Why will the console.log("Loaded") successfully executed?

Call it as dummy() and it executes when the statement is met in the parser

@mplungjan I found this way too. But, as said above in the question, in this case my script just separated into two large parts and prefer not to use this approach. Most things need to be transferred from the original 1st part  function to the new 2nd part function So I would be really appreciated if the load event can be resolved correctly and so the code can be looked logically continued.

What is the point of this code at all? Why use document.write? Why not just use inner HTML or an iFrame

@mplungjan You can forget about the document.write. Even I use the innerHTML method as below, the same happen:
dummy = function(){console.log("Dummy");} document.documentElement.innerHTML = tempDoc.documentElement.innerHTML; document.querySelector("body").onload = dummy;
If I put the resolve() after the .onload, the Dummy can be loaded correctly as the print of "Dummy" successfully triggered. But if I put resolve() inside the dummy finction, it just hang there forever.

The document has already loaded. You cannot use the onload or DOMContentLoaded because it has triggered before your code runs. You could use onload/load on an iFrame (I think, - it has been a while since I used them). And no need for promise/await. const dummy = () => { console.log('loaded')  }; const iFrame = document.getElementById('myIFrame');   iFrame.addEventListener("load",dummy); iFrame.document.write(strHTML);  iFrame.document.close();
